# Eclipse error "JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.1 can not be installed" / "...requires Java 1.8 or newer"

Tags: eclipse, jax-rs

When I try to build one of the modules within our application I keep getting two errors related to JAX-RS showing up in the "Problems"-view:

```
JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.1 can not be installed : One or more constraints have not been satisfied.
JAX-RS (REST Web Services) 2.1 requires Java 1.8 or newer.
```

The module that causes this error is the web-interface of a GWT (Google Web Toolkit) project that still uses GWT 2.7 which indeed requires Java 1.7 code. While we do compile using Java 1.8 we have set the compiler version (just for that GWT module) like so:

```
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            ...
```

What I don't get here is:

Why does JAX-RS interfere or come into play here at all?
That project (or maven "module") has neither a "Dynamic Web Module" facet nor a "JAX-RS (REST Web Service)"-facet. It also has no GWT-related facet, since the GWT plugin doesn't work anymore with the latest eclipse version.

Any idea anyone, where this JAX-RS error comes from? Or how to find out, what is causing this?

This is using the very latest Eclipse version as of today (Eclipse for WebDevelopers / v2022-12) freshly downloaded and installed and the projects imported into it.

Comment: Where do these errors present themselves?

Comment: @nitind in Eclipse's "Problems" view. I also added that to the description above.

Comment: What's in the Type column for those?

Answer (score 0):

I found that sometimes this error happens when setting up a new Jersey application in Eclipse. I don't know why this happens, but for anyone looking for how to fix this; right click on the project and from the context menu;

> Maven -> Update Project...
> Check 'Force Update of Snapshots/Releases'
> Click Ok

The error should go away.